# Регистрация через фейсбук на сайте

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, facebook-api

Я зарегистрировал приложение в фейсбуке, получил id и secret. Но когда пытаюсь обратиться к апи фейсбука, получаю ошибку.(прилагаю скрин)

[image: ошибка на клиенте]

Я так понял она связана с тем, что я что-то не разрешил на фейсбуке.
Может у кого-то знает, что надо разрешить в аккаунте?

Answer (score 0):

Не понятно, как вы делаете запрос, но мне помогло следующее:

```
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())
```